# run time error(null point exception) in creating a recursive tree

Tags: java, json, jtree

I want to take in the following as Json input and convert it into a tree data structure in java.

```
                {
                    "component": "A",
                    "status": 0,
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "component": "AA",
                            "status": 0,
                            "children": [
                                {
                                    "component": "AAA",
                                    "status": 0,
                                    "children": []
                                },
                                {
                                    "component": "AAB",
                                    "status": 0,
                                    "children": []
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "component": "AB",
                            "status": 0,
                            "children": [
                                {
                                    "component": "ABA",
                                    "status": 0,
                                    "children": []
                                },
                                {
                                    "component": "ABB",
                                    "status": 0,
                                    "children": []
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                }
```

I have written the following code but it shows runtime errors if any one can find the error. The for loop is executing till the point where there are no children for the node through recursion when it is supposed to return where it is showing the null pointer exception

```
            import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
            import java.io.FileReader;
            import java.io.IOException;
            import java.util.List;
            import java.io.BufferedReader;
            import org.json.*;

            public class Sample {

                public static void main(String[] args) {

                        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader( new FileReader("json.txt") );
                        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                        String line;
                        while ( ( line = in.readLine() ) != null ) {
                            builder.append(line);

                        object = new JSONObject( builder.toString() );
                        imlementation im = new imlementation();
                        im.createnode(object);                                                      
                }                   
            }
            public class node {
                    public String component;
                    public int status;
                    public List<node> children;
            }

            import org.json.JSONArray;
            import org.json.JSONException;
            import org.json.JSONObject;

            public class imlementation {

                public node createnode(JSONObject ob)
                {
                    node n = new node();
                    try
                    {
                        JSONArray children = ob.getJSONArray("children");
                        String component = ob.getString("component");
                        int status = ob.getInt("status");

                        n.component = component;
                        n.status = status;
                        n.children=null;
                        System.out.println( "component " + component + "status " + status );

                        int i;
                        for(i=0;i<children.length();i++)
                        {
                            n.children.add( createnode( children.getJSONObject( i ) ) );
                        }
                        return n;

                    }
                    catch ( JSONException ex ) 
                    {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }

                }
```

The stack Trace is

```
            java.lang.NullPointerException
                at imlementation.createnode(imlementation.java:30)
                at imlementation.createnode(imlementation.java:30)
                at SampleSample.main(SampleSample.java:45)
            java.lang.NullPointerException
                at imlementation.createnode(imlementation.java:30)
                at SampleSample.main(SampleSample.java:45)
```

Comment: Please give the exception stacktrace

Comment: Please add the stack trace and at which line you get the NPE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set

```
n.children=null;
```

and then in the for loop you are doing

```
n.children.add(....)
```

which is probably causing the Null pointer exception.

You probably need to do

```
n.children = new List<Node>()
```

before doing the add.

Another potential cause is children variable can be null during some recursive call. children.length would result in a null pointer exception.